# Is it possible to suppress certain activities from the activity feed messages in Alfresco?

Tags: alfresco

I am trying to suppress some messages in the activities feed for the document library and tried following the "chain of events" so to speak but I cannot find where in alfresco to suppress, for instance, the deleted files from activity feed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fastest approach to (globally) weed out certain types of events would be to drop a copy of  `activity.post.json.js` in `classes/alfresco/extension/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/slingshot/documentlibrary/activity.post.json.js` and tweak `postActivity` to ignore the events you want to get rid of. Alternatively,  you can override `activityPostService` defined in `alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/subsystems/ActivitiesFeed/default/activities-feed-context.xml` and filter out events there.

Finally, if you need to weed out activities at the user level, you might want to override `feedTaskProcessor`.